Hide a non-active app by clicking on its window
Is it possible (natively or using a third-party app) to hide (zap) non-active apps by clicking on their windows?
When having many windows open, I'd like to hold a button combo and click on the windows I'm not in need of to hide their apps. I'm well aware of the "hide others" command, which is not what I'm after. Let's say I have 6 windows open and I want to keep only three of them visible. Currently I need to switch to each of the other three apps and hide them manually.

What do you mean by "non-active"? You can Hide any app by right clicking on its icon in the Dock, without losing focus on the app you're using. Generally it's pretty easy to manage windows using Mission Control etc without needing to hide windows at all.

You might also want to look at Stage Manager

@benwiggy I guess I mean "unfocused", ie. all the other apps that aren't the current frontmost/focused app. And right clicking takes way too much time for what I'm after. But Mateusz mentioned that BTT can do it, so I'm all good!

You can do that using Better Touch Tool. It's a paid app, but can do much much more. Here's an example to do just that using "Corner Click Bottom Left"


Perfect! The one feature to finally convince me to try BTT. Thanks.
